# stretching a patternimage to the right

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've a `UITextField` that has a custom background image.

The image is 37px H and 3px W. The last pixel to the right has a border of 1px that I want to display at the end of the `UITextField` how could I stretch the image so that it the border only appears at the far right?

currently I tried

```
_exerciseName.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mychu.png"]];
```

but this creates a repetead pattern of my image.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are targeting iOS 5+ you are looking for the [`-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a) method otherwise the [`-[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW4)